# Error call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Queue\DatabaseQueue' does not have a method 'before'

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with my laravel project.

I have tried to composer update, but after update, error `call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Queue\DatabaseQueue' does not have a method 'before'`. before I update the composer, its normal.

This error appears every I run `php artisan serve` or other `php artisan`

My project using Laravel 5.1 and PHP 7.1

Please help

Comment: Have you tried `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: @Saengdaet yes i have tried, but same